# Oracle AQ dependent jars

Tags: oracle-aq

What are the jars dependent on Oracle AQ as I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory in the createQueueConnection(String,String) method

It looks like I'm missing some jar files. Can you please provide me suggestions on the complete list of jars that are required to run oracle aq calls?

Answer (score 1):

Required runtime jars are described in Programming Interfaces part in AQ user guide. Just scroll to "Using JDBC OCI Driver or JDBC Thin Driver"

[Using Oracle Java Message Service (Oracle JMS) to Access Oracle Database Advanced Queuing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADQUE/aq_envir.htm#ADQUE2540)

You need to copy jars from Oracle Database server and put them on class path.

Actually not all of them are required and it depends on what features you are using.